# Opening data channel fixo na conexão ftp

Tags: ftp

Estou tentando conectar a vários servidores FTP via linha de comando do DOS, porém sempre que tento, ele me retorna a linha

> 150 Opening data chanel for file upload to server of "< caminho do arquivo >"

E fica parado nesta mensagem para sempre, já tentei verificar portas, mas até pouco tempo atrás eu conseguia realizar esta conexão sem maiores problemas, porém agora ele apenas dá essa mensagem.

Quando verifico no servidor ele mostra a seguinte mensagem:

> 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "< caminho >"

O comando PORT está para (187,10,182,35,225,215). No modo passivo.

Comment: Pode ser que eu eu esteja errado, mas se não me engano o comando PORT é para uma conexão FTP ativa, onde o servidor se conecta a você, o que muitas vezes não funciona devido a firewalls ou mesmo routers. Se a conexão for mesmo passiva acho que o comando deveria ser o PASV.

Comment: Mas se fosse isso ele não funcionaria desde o começo... Esse bat funcionava antes, e parou de funcionar depois sem nenhum motivo aparente.